Was bedeutet "gerade eben noch mal"?
könntet ihr mir bitte sagen, was gerade eben noch mal bedeutet? I habe die Aussage in diesem video um 41 Sekunden. Hier is der Kontext:

Ich habe letzre Woche eine Einbauküche im Möbelhaus bei Ihnen gekauft. Jetzt habe ich gerade eben noch mal die Auftragsbestätigung durchgelesen.

I'd really appreciate it if you explained what kind of meaning the person is trying to convey by that combination of words.

Weißt du, was gerade eben bedeutet? Und noch mal?

Please ask your question in either German or English, but not both. The custom here is to answer in the language in which the question is asked, so it's confusing when people mix languages.

"Gerade eben" means "just a few moments ago".
"Noch mal" or "nochmal" or "noch einmal" means "once again".
The word "dir" is a typo in the sentence and should obviously be "die".
So the sentence uses a colloquial tone and means:

Jetzt habe ich gerade eben noch mal die Auftragsbestätigung durchgelesen.
I have just read through the order confirmation again.

(This translation is from DeepL and completely correct.)
